# how to move fixed slider to top when scrolling using CSS only

Tags: html, css

I want to move my fixed navigation to the top when I scroll down. I tried all my best but failed to do so.

Here is the code and for the question what exactly I am looking for.

Here is the [**Link**](http://demo.ikaruna.com/hermes/html/index1.html)

```css
#lower {
 background: #c8e600;
 background-image: url(images/headerimg.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 40px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: 60px;
 z-index: 100;
 opacity: 0.80;
}
#lower ul li a {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
 color:#000;
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-right: 2px;
 text-align: right;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 padding-top: 26px;
}
#lower ul li {
 padding: 10px;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding-left: 8px;
 float: right;
 list-style:none;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-right:0px;
 margin-top:0px;
 transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
#lower ul li a:hover {
 background:#FFF;
 transition: all 1.5s ease 0s;
}
#lower ul li:hover {
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 transition: transform 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="lower">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="theContact.html">the<strong>CONTACT</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">the<strong>BLOG</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">the<strong>TRAINERS</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">see<strong>SCHDULE</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">popular<strong>PROGRAMS</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our<strong>CLASES</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">why<strong>US</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="width:100%;overflow:auto"><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /> 
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</div>
```

Comment: you can do this using jQuery or javascript.

Comment: I don't know jQuery. I only know CSS, HTML and Javascript (basic).

Comment: you dont need to to anything just copy paste the code i posted. You h=just have to put a link of jQuery Library in <head> and my code.

Ok here it is jquery library.<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also please explain using JavaScript only if possible.....

Comment: Post updated, Pure Javascript solution is added. check my POst

Comment: awesome!!! man 10K Thanks.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS Changes:**

```
#lower
{
    margin-top:0;
    top:40px;
```

### }

**jQuery Solution:**

```
<head>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

NOTE: You must add jQuery library in `<head>`

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).on('scroll',function()
                  {
                       if(window.pageYOffset>180)
                       {
                           $('#lower').css({'top':'0px'});
                       }else
                       {
                            $('#lower').css({'top':'40px'});
                       }
                  });
})
</script>
```

***DEMO jQuery:***
https://jsfiddle.net/0andyke4/3/

---

**JavaScript Solution:**

```
<script>
     window.addEventListener("scroll",move);
        function move()
                      {
                           if(window.pageYOffset>180)
                           {
                               document.getElementById("lower").style.top = 0;
                           }else
                           {
                               document.getElementById("lower").style.top =40+'px';
                           }
                      }

</script>
```

***DEMO JavaScript:***
https://jsfiddle.net/0andyke4/7/

---

Comment: is it possible using javaScript only?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change header's position to absolute.

```
.header-1 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

It's also better if you change the scroll threshold to `30`:

```
if( scroll >= 30)
{
  $('.header-1, .header-2, .header-4 .header-4-inner, .menu-style- 5').addClass("sticky-navigation");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ONLY want to use CSS then the header must be fixed from the start. 
In the link you provided, the header starts off relative to the rest of the document. Once a certain scroll position is triggered, JAVASCRIPT it used to change the positioning from `relative` to `fixed`.

Without JavaScript, you could do something like this:

```css
.header {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#f00;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.page {
    margin-top:100px; /*height of the header*/
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="page">Page
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p><br /></p>
    long page...
</div>
```

Comment: I have done this before but I want to make the same as in the link given above.

Comment: then, @AsifAmeer you will not be able to do it without JavaScript